# How can I convert GitShell's commands into an .bat file?

Tags: git, windows, github

I'm on windows 8, I've installed GitHub, and there is also a GitShell.

I can add files to GitHub in GitShell via using git `add...`, ... `git push`, type username, type password

But I know little about how to convert it into a .bat file

How can I use a .bat file to complete the thing which done by commands in GitShell on windows and send files to GitHub?

[image]

Comment: Do you not understand the GitShell commands? Otherwise, you put them in a text file with the extension .bat and run it.

Comment: @Jeffo I can do the thing in GitShll, but I know little about how to convert it into a .bat file

Comment: An interesting [tutorial.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-overview)

Comment: are you trying to chain all the commands together or looking for something like autocompletion?

Comment: @Zavior yes, something like that! put all commands set in one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method on Windows 8.1:

Put the commands set used in GitShell in one .Bat file where the portable GitHub installed.

Run the .bat file, you will upload a "GitHub.nb" into the GitHub, you can use a program to generate the .bat files, I use Mathematica to do such things.

And you should type the username and password, you can download a assistant described in my Linked full-version to not do such things.

```
cd /d documents\github\hypergroups.github.com

git add"GitHub.nb"
git commit -a -m "something"
git push

pause
```

[Full version is here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30858/6648)